# Google add the domain name at the end of the search results

Tags: seo, google-search

I am not an SEO expert but I tought that Google use the `<title>` to display link in the search results. For a reason that I don't know, It add the domain at the end of the link. Does anybody have an idea why?

Web page source code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>
    Home | Le Boot Camp - Sleeman
  </title>
```

What Google display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google algorithmically re-writes titles and META descriptions that it doesn't think matches the pages' intent. It does this on a keyword basis and it happens the most with META descriptions. Try putting your branding at the end of your titles.

Comment: Kreezee is our brand, so you think I can't get rid of the brand? It was something that customer asked us, he want to see only "Le Boot Camp - Sleeman" in search results.

Comment: Its best practice to put your branding last in a title tag anyway so put it in, but keep it all under 70 characters. Use | as a separator as well. Titles and META use pixel width as a measure before they truncate.

Comment: Actually, the answer is far simpler than this. The title tag length is too short. Google will modify a title tag as a SERP link for a variety of reasons, the most common of which, is the title tag is too short. We have answered this question in detail many ways many times here. It is all condition based which is relatively easy to understand and manage. There are no fancy algorithms to consider. Just simple criteria. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Closetnoc, questions here: 1) How is my approach wrong? 2) How is any set of steps that computationally process and then re-write a <title> NOT an algorithm? 3) Why have you not provided links to other resources from all these discussions you've mentioned about <title> tags and Google's behaviour toward them to help provide a better solution to this question?